# Bluetooth 5.0 pairing but not connecting with Debian 11

Tags: audio, debian, bluetooth

I have Debian 11 Bullseye and KDE desktop installed on a HP Elitedesk machine, plus an Asus USB-BT500 adapter.  I can pair the device with the KDE Bluetooth application, and it shows my Bluetooth receiver called "D10" (the D10 unit is plugged into a HiFi audio receiver so I can hopefully listen to my computer (audio files) over my HiFi stereo).  KDE shows the device "D10" as headphones, which seems cool enough to me.  I click on it to connect and it can't connect, it says in big red letters "Protocol not available".

I tried using bash, with bluetoothctl, and was able to successfully pair the D10 to my computer, but when I try to connect, it can't, and it says, "Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed".  I tried to find a linux driver for my adapter but can't locate one.  Asus's website just says that the adapter works with Windows 8, 10 and Linux.

My bluetooth adapter does indeed work, as I have Windows 10 installed as a dual boot option, and I use my same machine and adapter to listen via the same D10 receiver to cool music from my computer to hifi, via Windows10.  But I can't find success with Debian 11 Bullseye.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Pipewire or Pulseaudio? If you're still on Pulseaudio, I'd strongly recommend you upgrade to Pipewire (it's drop-in so should be fairly seemless).

Pipewire fixes many of the shortcoming that Pulseaudio has with Bluetooth. For reference, see https://wiki.debian.org/BluetoothUser/a2dp and https://wiki.debian.org/PipeWire

Since Debian 11 has fairly old software, you might have to update to Debian Testing or Sid.

If you truly want to stick with Pulseaudio for the time being (and assuming this is what you're currently using), then try installing the [pulseaudio-module-bluetooth](https://packages.debian.org/pulseaudio-module-bluetooth) package and restarting your Bluetooth and audio stack:

```
# service bluetooth restart
$ killall pulseaudio
```

Comment: It appears that I'm using Pulseaudio.  I'm going to be giving this a try and will check back in a few days.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with the bluetooth service on a newly installed debian 11. I solved it by upgrading the kernel to 5.16, previously I had version 5.10.

You can check your kernel version you are using with `uname -r`.

[This tutorial](https://linuxhint.com/upgrade-kernel-in-debian-11-bullseye/) shows how to upgrade the linux kernel in debian to version 5.16.